# Population of infected people and proportionality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming a virus spreads through a population at a rate proportional to both the fraction of the population that is infected and the fraction that is not, the equation for the rage of change in the fraction $F$ of the population $P$ that is infected is just the logistical model, correct?

$F'(t)=kF(t)(P-F(t))$

If this is correct, any changes in $P$ or $F(t)$ would have an affect on $k$?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean it's a different model? If $k$ is related to the population and infected?

Comment: I have no clue, every logistical growth model I've seen is similar to what I wrote or use (1 - y/M)

Comment: Presumably the effect on $k$ comes from forcing the model with changed parameters to look the most similar to the original model or to still fit a data set? Without that you get just another solution, changed $k$ or not.